# MySQL query to get open and closed business_hour of shops

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-query-store

I do get open shops but when I want to print closed shops the query print open shop as closed. My Goal is to make the same query to print open and closed shops because now I have two different queries.

What is difficult for me is that restaurants could be open two times per day. For example Restuarant, open Monday at 10 am till Tuesday 03 am and Tuesday at 10 am till Wednesday 03 am.

I tried to make a CASE WHEN query but the problem was it could not get restaurant ID with printed status.

**My business_hour table with two inserted restaurants NOTE the restaurantID is a foreign key of a restaurant table.**

```
 id,restaurantID,openday,opentime,closeday,closetime
 1,15,Monday,10:00:00,Tuesday,03:00:00
 2,15,Tuesday,10:00:00,Wednesday,03:00:00
 3,24,Monday,10:00:00,Tuesday,03:00:00
 4,24,Tuesday,10:00:00,Wednesday,03:00:00
 5,24,Wednesday,10:00:00,Thursday,04:00:00
 6,24,Thursday,10:00:00,Friday,02:00:00
 7,24,Friday,10:00:00,Saturday,01:00:00
 8,24,Saturday,11:00:00,Sunday,01:00:00
 9,24,Sunday,11:00:00,Monday,02:00:00
```

The first below query print open restaurant perfectly.
How I get closed restaurants?

**query for checking open restaurants**

```
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM                         
                    business_hour 
                        INNER JOIN restaurant
                           ON business_hour.restaurantID = 
                            restaurant.id   
                    WHERE         
                     (closeday = '$today' AND closetime >= 
                      '$timeNow')  
                       OR
                     (openday = '$today' AND opentime <= 
                             '$timeNow')
                      ");  

        $stmt->execute();
        $i=0;
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $row['ravintolaID'].' '.'OPEN'.'  '.$row['openday'].' '.$row['opentime'].' --'.$row['closeday'].' '.$row['closetime'].' '.'<br>';

            $i++;   

        }
```

### I tried this query

**query for checking closed restaurants**

```
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM business_hour 
    INNER JOIN restaurant
   ON business_hour.restaurantID = restaurant.id    
    WHERE         
      (closeday = '$today' AND closetime < '$timeNow')  
           OR
       (openday = '$today' AND opentime > '$timeNow')
     ");    
    $stmt->execute();
        $i=0;
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $row['ravintolaID'].' '.'CLOSED'.' open at '.$row['openday'].' '.$row['opentime'].' --  '.$row['closeday'].' '.$row['closetime'].' '.'<br>';

            $i++;   

        }
```

I expect the output show me just one time closed and open restaurants.

The current day is **Monday** and Time is **7 am**

### OUTPUT

```
  24 OPEN Sunday 10:00:00 --Monday 08:00:00 
  15 CLOSED open at Monday 10:00:00 -- Tuesday 03:00:00 
  15 CLOSED open at Sunday 10:00:00 -- Monday 03:00:00 
  24 CLOSED open at Monday 10:00:00 -- Tuesday 03:00:00
```

Comment: @Strawberry not in use

Comment: @Strawberry I clear it, thanks for your advice

Comment: @Strawberry I just added Monday and Thursday data because It will be easy to understand the question, but same time restaurant open and close on Thursday too.

Comment: @Strawberry I added new line before output to show what is day and time set.

Comment: @Strawberry if it is Monday 7 am now, so restaurant number 15 should be open. I don’t have any problem with open because check the output it shows the opened restaurant. But the problem is second query and shows number 15 restaurant close and also number 24 but two times.

Comment: That's not answering my question, but essentially I don't think your data model is fit for purpose :-(

Comment: @Strawberry It could be open or not. It’s testing version. Now I test If a restaurant open two times per day.

Comment: @Strawberry do you have any idea, what time of data module should be fit for that.

Comment: @Strawberry I added number 24 restaurant's full business_hour.

Comment: @Strawberry It shows for me. Don’t know.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry. I was my mistake. I changed the restaurantId from 16 to 24. 

Comment: OK. It's getting clearer now. Is Monday the first day of the week

Comment: @Strawberry yes